# jQuery LineControl Editor does not work in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I am using Jquery LineControl editor in my project the problem is I am not able to get the text editor in edit mode. It displays a plain area without buttons.

Here is my code  :

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.message, new { @id = "txtEditor", @class = "form-control mediatext" })

  <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtEditor").Editor("message");
</script>
```

Displays like this without buttons

[image: Displays like this]

Comment: Did you include the LineControl Editor javascript link on the page?

Comment: Ye, I have added

Comment: Yes I have added javascript and css link

Comment: How to display the data which is coming from the database in text editor?

Comment: From the question, I assume you forgot to html decode the data from the database.